# How to determine if the SQL Server supports replication

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have a UI that needs certain portions to be disabled if the SQL Server it's connecting to does not support replication and which types of replication it supports (snapshot, merge, transactional). I looked through the doc for the SERVERPROPERTY function, but didn't see anything that looked like it was what I needed. Any suggestions?

Note - It would be preferable to not have to resort to switching on the Edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like there is no easy way to determine if replication is supported, however, it is possible to determine if the database is being replicated:

```
SELECT name, CASE WHEN is_published = 1 OR is_merge_published = 1 OR is_distributor = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS uses_replication FROM sys.databases
```

That's about as close as I can get I think.

Answer (score 0):

Even if a SQL Server instance is capable of doing replication, it is still not certain whether it is configured, and whether the administrator has it active.

For all these uncertainties, the most useful application solution is to define a flag in one of your application's tables indicating whether the replication-related logic should be enabled.  This also makes system testing simple.

Comment: Well, in this case, the application is an interface for configuring/managing the SQL Server. I really need to be able to *detect* support as it will not be known when we are building the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set up replication using the objects of the [Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.replication.replicationserver%28SQL.90%29.aspx) in a Try Catch block.  If it bombs, then disable the replication portion of your app.

Comment: Well, I'm looking to do this on a web server, where the Microsoft.SqlServer assemblies may not be installed. It would be preferable to do this using a TSQL query.